# Grab unique data attribute values and create key-value array from these?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have a number of data-attributes on page which will have different values, but there will be duplicates of these values, for example:

```
<div data-user-val="[Adult-Young-25]"></div>
<div data-user-val="[Adult-Young-25]"></div>
<div data-user-val="[Adult-Young-25]"></div>
<div data-user-val="[Adult-Mid-35]"></div>
<div data-user-val="[Adult-Mid-35]"></div>
<div data-user-val="[Adult-Old-75]"></div>
```

I want to loop through and grab each unique value ('[Adult-Young-25]','[Adult-Mid-35]','[Adult-Old-75]') and split these up to pass to an array as key-value pairs like:

```
var array = {"Adult Young": "25", "Adult Mid": "35", "Adult Old": "75"};
```

I'm struggling to 1. grab one instance of each repeated data value, and 2.  to 'split' the value to map as key-value pairs.

Comment: Post some code that you have tried and perhaps not working

Comment: It works if all attributes have the same amounts of delimiters (here -). Yet I would recommend to use the actual attribute name (data-adult-young, data-adult-mid) as attribute name with the  actual value (25, 35, 75) instead. Would make it much easier.

Comment: @Lain the structure of the data attribute is unfortunately out of my control, so I need to work with [Adult-Young-25] for example.

Comment: Can there be a [Adult-Young-26]?

Comment: @Lain absolutely there could be. That's why I need to ensure I grab each unique value only once.

Comment: @Lain from below, the fact that it's not appearing in the resulting object is the issue!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var obj = {};

$('div').each(function(){
  var data_attrivute_value = $(this).data('user-val');
  data_attrivute_value = data_attrivute_value.substring(1,data_attrivute_value.lastIndexOf("]"));
  var exploded_string = data_attrivute_value.split('-');
  obj[exploded_string[0]+' '+exploded_string[1]] = exploded_string[2];
});

console.log(obj);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-user-val="[Adult-Young-25]"></div>
<div data-user-val="[Adult-Young-25]"></div>
<div data-user-val="[Adult-Young-25]"></div>
<div data-user-val="[Adult-Mid-35]"></div>
<div data-user-val="[Adult-Mid-35]"></div>
<div data-user-val="[Adult-Old-75]"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) to get all elements with the `data-user-val` attribute, and spread to array. Iterate the array with [`Array.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce), and get the value of the attribute. Use [`String.match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) to get the non numeric (key) and the numeric (value) parts of the value. Assign the key and value to the object.

```js
const result = [...document.querySelectorAll('[data-user-val]')]
  .reduce((r, el) => {
    const [, k, v] = el.getAttribute('data-user-val').match(/([^\d\[]+)(\d+)/);
    
    r[k.replace(/-/g, ' ').trim()] = v;
    
    return r;
  }, {});
  
console.log(result);
```

```html
<div data-user-val="[Adult-Young-25]"></div>
<div data-user-val="[Adult-Young-25]"></div>
<div data-user-val="[Adult-Young-25]"></div>
<div data-user-val="[Adult-Mid-35]"></div>
<div data-user-val="[Adult-Mid-35]"></div>
<div data-user-val="[Adult-Old-75]"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple solution without any fancy libraries or functions:

```
var divs = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
var myAttr = 'data-user-val';
var dict = {};

for(i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
  var val = divs[i].getAttribute(myAttr);
  if (val) {
    var trimmed = val.substr(1, val.length - 2)
    var splitted = trimmed.split('-');
    var key = splitted[0] + ' ' + splitted[1];
    if (!dict.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      dict[key] = splitted[2];
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: The code would fail if one div in the whole document did not have an attribute called 'data-user-val'.

Comment: true, fixed now

Comment: Why not just only select the correct divs? Looping through 1000 divs takes alot more time than just ~10 :-)

Comment: because `getElementsByTagName` is more reliable than `querySelectorAll`, as it's updated every time you check the value.
So if there would be an update from backend and you'll get more `div`s, then my code will correctly update the `dict`.

Comment: here you have an example:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18247289/what-is-the-difference-between-queryselector-and-getelementsbytagname#answer-30921553

Comment: Yes, I am aware of this. Yet _normally_ random divs dont just suddenly appear out of nowhere, so I do not see the use of it here. Yet that is just my taste :-)