# Puppeteer.js : get href attribute of link with given text

Tags: javascript, node.js

is there a way in puppeteer to get the href attribute of an anchor element with text "See more".

I want to grab the href attribute of an element like this:

```
<a href="/this-is-what-i-want">See more</a>
```

maybe it's possble to do with eval?

Answer (score 0):

you could try looping through all links

```
document.querySelectorAll('a').forEach(link => link.innerText === "See more"  )
```

This might not work with newer JavaScript versions since `querySelectorAll` as well as `getElementsByTagName` do not [yield](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18247289/what-is-the-difference-between-queryselectorall-and-getelementsbytagname) an Array but `HTMLCollection` which is [not iterable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35970005) using `forEach`. See the linked answers on SO on how to fix this.

Answer (score -1):

maybe you should try native js

```
url=document.getElementById("Id_of_AnchorTag").href;
```

keep in mind that you must be able to uniquely identify the anchor by some method.

Comment: This is not using puppeteer.